# iTunes -- How much time iTunes takes to update newly released version of application on Store

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes

I have updated new version of iOS application on Apple iTunes. After it got approved today morning i released version. 
Its been more than 5 hrs still i can't see updated version on iTunes. It still shows old version when i open up URL:
https://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=xxxx&mt=8

I have checked it from multiple regions but its showing same version.

Any idea how long it may take for newer version to get reflected.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the current status of the app. Make sure it's not pending developer release, in which case it won't go live on the App Store until you tell it to. If it's saying processing for App Store, then it can take up to 24 hours to actually show in the store. If it's saying ready for sale but you can't see it, then wait 24 hours and contact iTunes Connect support if it's still not showing.

Comment: App State is already "Ready for Sale" but i can't see update even after 24 hrs. Finally now i have dropped an email to iTunes connect. Lets see what they say.

Comment: I've had this problem in the past. They had to do something their end to make it go live even though it said Ready for Sale. IIRC, it showed up almost immediately after that.

Answer (score 0):

Finally its resolved. 
Sent request to Apple to check status of application as new version is showing as Ready to Sale. Finally they have refreshed app from their side. Now new version of app is live!

Comment: I'm glad it's sorted now :) Please could you accept my answer if it was helpful? Thanks :)